# AWS Userdata not working on Windows server 2019

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, pm2

**Current setup:**

Manually launched Windows server 2019 instance with nodes app in AWS.
Below commands are working fine with this instance

```
Pm2 delete myapp
Pm2 start
```

**Issue :**

We have created AMI of the above instance and launched it with a cloudformation template.
In the userdata of cloudformation template, we have made some changes in the config file of nodejs and restarting the nodes app with the above commands.

**Output:**

config file modified  successfully with cloduformation userdata

**Error:**

The above commands (Pm2 delete myapp and Pm2 start) failed in the execution of userdata. below is the userdata log.

```
The errors from user scripts: pm2 : The term 'pm2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Windows\TEMP\UserScript.ps1:15 char:1
+ pm2 delete RenderWorker
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pm2:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
pm2 : The term 'pm2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Windows\TEMP\UserScript.ps1:16 char:1
+ pm2 start
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pm2:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**Other findings:**

Pm2 command is available with newly launched ec2 instance.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>pm2
usage: pm2 [options] <command>

pm2 -h, --help             all available commands and options
pm2 examples               display pm2 usage examples
pm2 <command> -h           help on a specific command

Access pm2 files in ~/.pm2
```

Userdata in cloudofrmation:

```
 UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      <powershell>
      $config = '{
      "MyENV": "${MyENV}",
      "UR1L": "${URL1}",
      "URL2": "${URL2}",
      "BUCKET": "${MyBucket}",
      "PATH": "${Mypath}"
      }'
      echo $config
      $config | Set-Content C:\Projects\myapp\settings\config.json
      cd 'C:\Projects\myapp'
      pm2 delete RenderWorker
      pm2 start
      </powershell>
      <runAsLocalSystem>true</runAsLocalSystem>
      <persist>true</persist>
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can run `pm2` directly like that because the path to `pm2` does not exist under SYSTEM path.

You are likely required to include the full path of it as follows to run the command.

For example, your `pm2` resides under `C:\etc\` then you need to include as follows:

```
C:\etc\.pm2 delete RenderWorker
C:\etc\.pm2 start
```

or if you are familiar with the path, you can make it as an environment variable.

Comment: is it because of my .pm2 is under administrator directory . C:\Users\Administrator\.pm2 ?